# How to detect lack of specific field in payload and handle it via exception in Django?

Tags: python, django, request, pycharm, body-parser

I have a method like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_method(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = json.loads(request.body)
        try:
            name = payload['name']
            return HttpResponse("YES", content_type='text/json')
        except payload['name'].DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("NO", content_type='text/json')
```

So i want detect and handle error when frontend device not send **name** field in body. At the moment i have getting several errors when not send **name** field in body. Please help me to fix this as well i receive better way.

Comment: Question is unclear. Please add some explanation to your question. Also fix the code indentation.

Comment: @Ram please check again.

Comment: @Ram NameError at /my_url
name 'field' is not defined

Comment: Also include what error messages you are gettiing. The complete traceback of the error. We cannot help you without knowing the complete error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It might work.

```
name = payload.get('name',None)
if not name:
    return HttpResponse("NO", content_type='text/json')
else:
    return HttpResponse("YES", content_type='text/json')
```